# AWS MSK Connect with Mongo DB as the Source

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, aws-msk

We are planning to have an MSK created in AWS with Mongo DB as the Source for the MSK.  We do not see any Pre-defined Connectors for connecting to the Mongo DB as source.

How to setup a connector?

Do we need to create a Connector completely or are there built in connectors available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSK Connect to install and provision whatever connectors you want [via plugins](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-plugins.html).

This includes Debezium's Mongo connector, or the source connector provided by Mongo themselves, which are "available to download" ; not sure what you mean "pre-defined".

After this, consult the official documentation for the connector of your choice for its own config properties and use HTTP requests to submit it to the cluster